# Question on a proof involving the Cramér model

Tags: probability-theory, number-theory

This is a question on one part from Tao's note: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/01/04/254a-supplement-4-probabilistic-models-and-heuristics-for-the-primes-optional/. Refer to Prediction $3$ (Riemann hypothesis).

Construct a random model ${{\mathcal P}'}$ of the primes ${{\mathcal P}}$ to be a random subset of the natural numbers, such that each natural number ${n > 2}$ has an independent probability of ${\frac{1}{\log n}}$ of lying in ${{\mathcal P}'}$, and let us require that ${1 \not \in {\mathcal P}'}$ and ${2 \in {\mathcal P}'}$.

We consider the random variables

$\displaystyle X_n := 1_{{\mathcal P}'}(n) \log n - 1$.

Then the ${X_n}$ have mean zero and are independent, and have size ${O( \log x ) = O( x^{o(1)} )}$. It is then stated that

> Thus $\displaystyle \mathop{\bf E} (\sum_{2 < n \leq x} X_n)^k = O_k( x^{k/2+o(1)})$
> for any fixed natural number ${k}$ (the only terms in ${(\sum_{2 < n \leq x} X_n)^k}$ that give a non-zero contribution are those in which each ${X_n}$ appears at least twice, so there are at most ${k/2}$ distinct indices of ${n}$ that arise, and so there are only ${O_k(x^{k/2})}$ such terms, each contributing ${O(x^{o(1)})}$. From Chebyshev’s inequality this implies that ${\sum_{n \leq x} X_n = O( x^{1/2+\varepsilon})}$ with probability ${1-O( x^{-k\varepsilon + o(1)})}$.

**Question:** (1). The ${O_k(x^{k/2})}$ terms with a non-zero contribution to the sum
$\displaystyle \mathop{\bf E} (\sum_{2 < n \leq x} X_n)^k$ are those in which each ${X_n}$ appears at least twice, so for example, if $k = 5$, then $X_i^2 X_j^3$ is such a term, why do the expectation of such terms equal $O(x^{o(1)})$?

(2). Why does Chebyshev's inequality imply the given bound ${\sum_{n \leq x} X_n = O( x^{1/2+\varepsilon})}$ with probability ${1-O( x^{-k\varepsilon + o(1)})}$?

Answer (score 0):

(1) Even the maximum of each term of the form $\prod_{j=1}^k X_{n_j}$ is $O(x^{o(1)})$, so the expectation certainly is as well.

(2) Are you able to bound the variance of $\sum_{2<n\le x} X_n$ with the given bound? What happens when you input that bound into Chebyshev's inequality?

Comment: For (2), the variance is bounded by $O(x^{1+o(1)})$, and the mean by $O(x^{1/2+o(1)})$, do we insert these bounds into Chebyshev? and what threshold $t$ in ${\bf P}(|X - {\bf E}X| \geq t)$ is being used here?